# rails 3 routing... unable to pass param[:n_id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

What am I doing wrong here?

Routing File

```
  match '/ignore/:n_id',:to => 'businesses#ignore', :as => 'ignore'
```

Index

```
<%= link_to "Ignore", ignore_path(@n_ignore = o.n_id) %>
```

Resulting url (which is correct)

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/ignore/47
```

Controller (where i'm hoping to do some stuff with the n_id)

```
def ignore
      @searchresultignore = params[:n_id]
end
```

After redirecting back to the index page i have a null value

```
<%= debug @searchresultignore %>
```

Comment: Please show the controller code that does the redirecting.  Please show the full index action in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A controller's instance variables aren't shared across requests, if you're redirecting to the `index` action and still need that parameter, you should use something like:

```
redirect_to :action => :index, :n_id => params[:n_id]
```

Comment: that makes sense... however, I'm even able to get @searchresultsignore populated in def ignore. any idea how to get that working?   Sorry i'm a noob

Comment: Then assign `@searchresultsignore` inside the index action as this is where you need it. Also consider using `params[:n_id]` directly inside your view instead of creating an instance variable.